# Update xml file in JAR with weblogic deployment plan

Tags: java, deployment, jar, weblogic, configuration-files

I have a java application(not a EJB, not a MDB, it has a class implements ApplicationLifecycleListener). I build this java application into a jar file then create an EAR file include this jar, deploy the EAR file on a weblogic server, it works perfectly fine.

Now I want to use weblogic deployment plan to update some of the values in a configuration file which located inside the jar file. I generated the deployment plan, but it does not recognize my configuration XML file. I tried manually add it to the deployment plan, and use the deployment plan to redeploy this application. But nothing is updated.

I have read some examples of updating ejbs, but did not find anything about update a JAR's configuration inside an EAR, can anyone please give me example or send leave a link on how to properly use weblogic deployment plan to update a configuration file inside a JAR which is packed within an EAR file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to place the XML file in a jar file with same name under the same path as the original and use this jar in AppFileOverrides.